# How to To Filter wp_enqueue_script() Scripts on Some Pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using following code to add some scripts in WP pages like

```
function add_js() {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'colorbox-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'img-loader', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/img-load.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'box-tanzim', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/tanzim.js', array('jquery'),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts-js', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'),'',true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js' );
```

but I don't want to add unnecessary scripts on some pages! for example I would like to have all of above scripts on `front-page.php` but on other pages I don't need last three scripts.

Can you please let me know how I can filter them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this maybe

```
if ( is_page_template( 'front-page.php' ) ) {
    // wp_enqueue_script()
}
```

Comment: Hi Dhaval, can I also use this code fir other templates? for example `if ( is_page_template( 'page-products.php' ) ) {
    // wp_enqueue_script()
}` thanks

Comment: i don't think it should be an issue but just make sure the path to the file is right..

Comment: what do you mean by `path of file`? arent they all in theme folder?

Comment: if your file is in a sub folder then you would have to take that into consideration..for e.g : is_page_template( 'templates/about.php' ); also refer to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/ for more info